# Setting height and width of element in rems using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

How can I set the width/height of an element in rems using javascript?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
    function generateProgressItems(count)
    {
        console.log("doing it...");
        let container = document.getElementById("progress-container");
        for(var i=0; i<count; ++i)
        {
            console.log("creating image");
            let img = document.createElement('img'); 
            img.src =  'lock_closed.png'; 
            img.width = "100rem";
            img.height ="100rem";
            container.appendChild(img); 
        }
    }
```

This seems not to be working and width/height is set to 0

Comment: you probably want to use `img.style.width` - `.width` is the html element image width attribute which only accepts integers without units

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/width, as @Pete said, `img.width` and `img.height` only accept unit-less numbers. These will be become pixel values.

Comment: So, I guess I will have to do the conversion by hand... weird :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I added a background color so you can see the space for the image even if for some reason the PNG does not load.

```js
function generateProgressItems(count) {
    "use strict";

    let container = document.getElementById("progress-container");

    for (var index=0; index < count; ++index) {
    
        let img = document.createElement("img"); 
        img.src =  "lock_closed.png"; 
        img.style.background = "blue";
        img.style.width = "2rem"; //100rem is fine too
        img.style.height ="2rem"; //but it's huge.
        container.appendChild(img); 
    }
}

generateProgressItems(5);
```